# Removing Class from div after change in another div (Wordpress Contact Form 7)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm triying to remove a class from DIV after WP Contact Form 7 sent a form. I've found a code in other sites but is not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var outputBlock = $(".wpcf7-response-output");
var SuccessMessage = document.querySelector(".download-catalog-success");
$(".wpcf7-submit").click(function () {
    //Start an interval check after submit has been clicked
    var intervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
        if (outputBlock.hasClass("wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")) {
            // The form has been submitted successfully, remove the hidden class from the success message
            SuccessMessage.classList.remove("uk-hidden");
            // Stop running the interval checker after class has been added
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wordpress has a script which removes the $("") functionality.

You have to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` everywhere.

Also if you are using a post editor, it most likely filters out `<script>` tags so you may need an additional plugin to be able to add javascript to specific posts